# Create audio element dynamically with createElement instead of getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have a bit of javascript which runs like this:

```
document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML = ("<audio id=\"player\" src=\"data:audio/x-wav;base64,"+encode64(wav)+"\">");
return document.getElementById("player");
```

I would like to change it to something like this:

```
audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = "data:audio/x-wav;base64,"+encode64(wav)+"\">";
document.body.appendChild(audio);
return audio;
```

But, this does not work in the same way. Why is this not essentially equivalent in returning an element with a `play` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src` should not have the close tag part:

```
//                                                  ↓↓↓↓↓↓
audio.src = "data:audio/x-wav;base64,"+encode64(wav)+"\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra `"\">"` at the end.

```
audio.src = "data:audio/x-wav;base64,"+encode64(wav)+"\">";
```

Comment: so close ... so, is the appendChild even good form or can I even just omit that?

Comment: @karley why don't you try it and see?

Comment: You have to use `appendChild` there.

Comment: it works without it on chrome here but I'm skeptical that it's a good thing to omit.