# Javascript/html5 play multiple audio files or overlap audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, dom-events

Let me start by saying I am trying to play a mp3 file whenever the player collides with a wall, simple enough and done. But I wish to have another sound file play when the player hits another wall. 
I have tried using both `<audio>` tag in the html file, than playing it in Javascript:

```
var sound = document.getElementById("TheHtml5Tag");
```

Still the same issue, only one sound can be played, the next sound won't play untill the first one is finished. **Even when using multiple `<audio>` tags and multiple sounds.**
Next I have tried using codes similar too:

```
sound = new Audio('Wall_Hit_01.mp3'); 
sound.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
}, false);
```

Than playing it with: `sound.play();`
But still the same issue: I can't play `sound2.play();` or `sound3.play();` before the first sound has finished.
Any answers/ suggestions are much appreciated. If there isn't a way to do this on every browser maybe some tips on how too stop all the sounds in order to play a new sound would be nice. Though I would much rather go with the original question.

Comment: Did you manage to work this out perhaps? I have similar issues with sounds in browser still … If you have please consider answering my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006776/cross-browser-and-cross-device-audio

Comment: See my question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360874/dynamically-created-html5-audio-is-not-playable-in-some-browsers/23511373#23511373

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006776/cross-browser-and-cross-device-audio

Answer (score 3):

I found a pretty neat solution that utilizes pure JavaScript.

In my HTML File, I put two audio elements and a play audio buttons in the same div.

```
<div id="audioplay">
<audio id='audio1' src="ex1.wav" type="audio/wav" preload="auto" autobuffer controls ></audio>
<audio id='audio2' src="ex2.wav" type="audio/wav" preload="auto" autobuffer controls></audio>
<button id='playaudio' onclick='playAudio()'>Play Audio</button>
```

In my JS file (you could use a script tag too), I put this code, which plays both of the files. Make sure that your audio src tags point to the right place!

```
function playAudio(){
    var audio1 = document.getElementById('audio1');
    var audio2 = document.getElementById('audio2');
    audio1.play();
    audio2.play();
}
```