# Supporting Audio Tags in mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

is there any possibility to use the  Tag in mobile browsers?
It only works in my Desktop-Browser and not on my smartphone.
I tried it with the -Tag and with adding it by Javascript, both doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

I used this code:

```
var audio = document.create('audio');
audio.setAttribute('src', 'my-surce.mp3');
audio.play();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can check [Cross-browser and cross-device audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006776/cross-browser-and-cross-device-audio) for more info.

Otherwise its probably the easiest to use one of the libraries such as [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS), [Howler](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library) or [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) but be warned: they all have one or two drawbacks which you won't be able to overcome. But audio should play normally most of the time on most devices with all of them if used properly...

SoundJS has [mobile safe approach](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/) also which you might find interesting. [Here](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS/demos) you can check some demos and see if this is something you need.